# What is a right CLS-compliant naming convention for protected fields?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

I am developing a CLS-compliant types library and I have a class inside It, which contains private, protected and public fields and properties. I use underscore symbol (_) as prefix for private or protected fields and little first letter to distinct their from properties with same names. It looks so:

```
class SomeClass
{
private int _age; //Here is OK

public int Age { get { return this._get; } }
}
```

But when I try to use protected fields I collide with a next problem:

```
class SomeClass
{
protected int _age; //Here is NOT CLS-compliant (because of _ can't be the first symbol of identifier)

public int Age { get { return this._get; } }
}
```

Then I tried to do in such way:

```
class SomeClass
{
protected int age; //Here is NOT CLS-compliant (because of age and Age differ only in one symbol)

public int Age { get { return this._get; } }
}
```

Please, tell me, what is right CLS-compliant notation or convention between developers for such cases? Have I to use prefixes in C-style like l_age?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a more correct version, IMO:

```
private int _age;
public int Age {
    get { return this._age ; }
    protected set { this._age = value; }
}
```

or simply:

```
public int Age { get; protected set; }
```

If you properly encapsulate it, then it *doesn't matter* what the field is called, as **nothing** outside that type can see it.

---

In comments, the question of events is then raised, with the example:

```
protected EventHandler<StateChangedEventArgs> _stateChanged;
public event EventHandler<StateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged
{
    add { lock (this.StateChanged) { this._stateChanged += value; } }
    remove { lock (this.StateChanged) { this._stateChanged -= value; } }
}
```

Here I again assert that there is **no** reason for this field to be protected; the event *does not belong* to the derived class. It has 2 sensible operations it can want to perform:

1. invoke the event
2. subscribe/unsubscribe to the event

The former should be done via the `On*` pattern; the latter should just use the regular accessors (otherwise it violates the lock). Also, *even if* we assume that `lock(this.StateChanged)` is a typo (that would be a really, really bad thing to use as the lock object -it ***would not work at all***), note that in C# 4.0 the compiler has a much more efficient lock strategy inbuilt (that uses `Interlocked` rather than `Monitor`) when you write a "field-like" event (i.e. no explicit `add`/`remove`). Consequently, the preferred approach here would be:

```
public event EventHandler<StateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged;
protected virtual void OnStateChanged(StateChangedEventArgs args) {
    var snapshot = StateChanged; // avoid thread-race condition
    if(snapshot != null) shapshot(this, args);
}
```

and... that's it!

- if the subclass wants to subscribe/unsubscribe (not ideal, but meh) it just uses `StateChanged +=` and `StateChanged -=`
- if the subclass wants to invoke the event, it calls `OnStateChanged(...)`
- if the subclass wants to tweak the event logic, it adds an `override` to `OnStateChanged`

no need for any non-private fields.

Comment: Mmm...What to do with events?

Comment: @Praetor12 what *about* events? what does the derived class need access to the field for there? Perhaps add a specific event-related example?

Comment: Yes It is. Base-class has an event, which is called by derived-class methods. For such mechanism I did so:
        
        protected EventHandler<StateChangedEventArgs> _stateChanged;

        
        public event EventHandler<StateChangedEventArgs> StateChanged;
        {
            add { lock (this.StateChanged) { this._stateChanged += value; } }
            remove { lock (this.StateChanged) { this._stateChanged -= value; } }
        }

Comment: @Praetor12 if your `lock` was actually as per http://pastie.org/2599084, then note that *that too* is **not** actually a functioning `lock` strategy, even though the compiler does not give a warning. It does not fulfil the intended purpose of the `lock`.

Comment: Even though this might be a better solution. This totally does not answer the question posed. I.e. what is the naming convention for protected fields...

Comment: @TimDams - that's because no "official" convention exists - and I point out why in my answer - Microsoft have always recommended that such beasts should not exist.

Answer (score 2):

To back up Marc's answer, the guidance on [Field Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057.aspx) from Microsoft states:

> Public and protected fields do not version well and are not protected by code access security demands. Instead of using publicly visible fields, use private fields and expose them through properties.

This is probably why you will not find any useful guidance on naming them (in fact, the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx) just point back at the Field Design page).